# Bower and Gulp changing file paths in distribution

Tags: gulp, bower

Started learning Bower and Gulp. I have app directory where I will do my development and a dist directory where the final project will live ready to go out to the world.

In my app directory I have installed chart.js through bower and therefore it is in a folder called bower_components/chart.js.

In my index.html file I have a link to Chart.js as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/chart.js/Chart.js"></script>
```

In my distribution I want this to be in my javascript folder

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Chart.js"></script>
```

How do I automate changing the location of the Chart.js file in Gulp?

I imagine this is a general requirement considering your distribution file structure is different to your development file structure.